# How to provide inputs to charts which is given by DanielGindi(ChartsDemo) in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I have imported the ChartsDemo swift file library which is given by danielGindi in github to my objective c file.Now i want to check the charts by providing input values.Am new to chart Concepts.Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: At least provide the link to the library, and some sample code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow some tutorials about iOS chart library. For example this one: http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/

In few word you should:
 1. Associate your view with chart class;
 2. Create an outlet;
 3. Prepare data;
 4. Assigned data with data property.

Example code with random data below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,  ChartViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var chartView: LineChartView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set x values
    let count = 10
    var xVals: [String]! = []
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            xVals.append("\(i)")
        }

    //set y values
    let range = 5.0
    var yVals: [ChartDataEntry] = []
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            let val = drand48() * range + 35
            yVals.append(ChartDataEntry(value: val, xIndex: i))
        }

    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(yVals: yVals, label: "DataSet 1"

    // set Data
    var dataSets: [LineChartDataSet] = []
    dataSets.append(set1)
    let chartData = LineChartData(xVals: xVals, dataSets: dataSets)
    chartView.data = chartData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the library you are referring to (https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts). In the folder for the project the author has given a sample project which shows how to use Swift file in the Objective-c file for this library, you can check that out.Tell if more information is required.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks...but I want to know how to provide input for chart....after importing chart and I run means just it shows white screen....I I'll upvote if u provide explanation....

Comment: This is t link: https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts .how to give the input and how it works...anybody tell me overall idea...am a newbie to charts...